# How to parse a list of named ES6/ES2015 exports from a module?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I want to parse the text content of a javascript file for export statements and extract a list of named exports from the module.

Why? I'm looking to extend [`import-js`](https://github.com/Galooshi/import-js)'s Meteor environment to understand local packages and the main hold-up seems to be being able to parse and identify the named exports of each package.

The existing implementation identifies the package name, path and isopack so I can easily get the path to the `mainModule` of each package. I just need help parsing that file for export statements.

Comment: to provide additional context, you might include some strategies you've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`babylon`](https://github.com/babel/babylon) to generate a JavaScript AST of an input file, and then check the top level for `ExportDefaultDeclaration`, `ExportNamedDeclaration`, and `ExportAllDeclaration`. Given the following example:

```
export default test;
export { foo as bar, baz };
export let lol = "okay then"; // also var, const
export * from 'import-js';
```

[Babylon 7 generates this AST](https://astexplorer.net/):

[image: Babylon 7 AST]

You can use [this list of various supported syntaxes for `export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and use [the explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) to see what Babylon is expected to generate, and then you can use the resulting JSON to get the parsed information you need.

Comment: Cheers, any advice for parsing the syntax tree to grab all the exports?
Especially when an `ExportAllDeclaration` points to another file(s)?

Comment: @FrederickStark I don't understand your comment about the node "points to another file". It's just a plain object that contains information about the syntax, but you can use [this documentation](https://github.com/babel/babylon/blob/master/ast/spec.md#exports) to understand what the properties mean.

Comment: Unlike the other types If you look in the `ExportAllDeclaration` it doesn't include any identifiers naming the things being exported, so you need to parse the file that statement refers to and continue down the chain till all exports have been discovered. Was just asking if you had advice on a way to do so

Comment: Wrong. Check the `source` property, as indicated in the AST explorer AND the documentation! That contains the identifier...

Comment: [If you look at the explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/16aa283ba4e0c7abc9c0056fab5e0551/55a6c1cdeb6a99be28610e78075d32b99150449b), there are no Identifiers (named exports from the other file) for an `ExportAllDeclaration`. `source` only contains the 'from' string from `export * from ***'./foo'***`. 

I ended up solving it by feeding the referenced file back into the parser. Was just hoping you had advice on the best way to do so. 

No need to be rude by declaring I'm wrong, using caps and exclamation marks when it's just a misunderstanding

Comment: @FrederickStark don't be daft, it's right here, in the link you sent, no less: http://i.imgur.com/eAp67NC.png

Comment: Are you pulling my leg? Do you see the names of exported symbols anywhere on that picture? Or do you see the name of the file, like I explained. Also note that the word "Identifier" doesn't appear either

Comment: You said it only contained the string 'from'. Of course it's just the file name, babylon is a syntax parser, not an interpreter or compiler. I'm glad you solved it, but no there's no easy way to do this, other than calling it recursively.